# Inno Setup: Ready Page custom layout

Tags: inno-setup

The UX designer's call. I am reworking layout for Ready Page to make it similar to Welcome Page as in my drawing:

[image: UX Designer wants Ready Page to look more like Welcome page]

The two slides above are standard pages. The one on the bottom is reworked Ready Page. How can I reposition all the controls and text labels to accomplish that?

P.S.
*I accepted the answer from Martin Prikryl and the most important part was the structure from Wizard.dfm.txt. The exact answer was not fully applicable partially due to the sketch above being simplification of the problem with upgrading the installation project to use with [Graphic Installer](http://graphical-installer.com) plug-in for Inno Setup.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`TWizardForm` class](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents) has a structure like (.dfm format):

```pascal
object OuterNotebook: TNewNotebook
  object WelcomePage: TNewNotebookPage
    object WizardBitmapImage: TBitmapImage
    object WelcomeLabel2: TNewStaticText
    object WelcomeLabel1: TNewStaticText
  end
  object InnerPage: TNewNotebookPage
    object Bevel1: TBevel
    object InnerNotebook: TNewNotebook
      ...
      object ReadyPage: TNewNotebookPage
        object ReadyMemo: TNewMemo
        object ReadyLabel: TNewStaticText
      end
      ...
    end
    object MainPanel: TPanel
      object WizardSmallBitmapImage: TBitmapImage
      object PageDescriptionLabel: TNewStaticText
      object PageNameLabel: TNewStaticText
    end
  end
end
```

Note how the "Welcome" page is on a different level of the hierarchy than the "Ready" page.

For full details, see [`Wizard.dfm`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/main/Projects/Wizard.dfm).

---

To do what you ask for, in the `InitializeWizard` [event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents):

- Create copy of the `WizardBitmapImage` on the `ReadyPage`;
- Shrink the `ReadyMemo` and `ReadyLabel` accordingly (use `WelcomeLabel2.Left` and `.Width` as a guide).

When the user proceeds to the "Ready" page, in the `CurPageChanged` event function (with `CurPageID = wpReady`).

- Hide the `MainPanel` (probably also `Bevel1`);
- Resize the `InnerPage` to stretch over the space left by the `MainPanel`. You can probably just make it as large as its parent `InnerPage` is.

(And undo this if the user presses "Back").